# Write pdf from FormData object

Tags: javascript, node.js, form-data

i'm developing a web application using html, javascript and nodejs.
I have to store on the server some pdfs and so the way that i found to send pdf from client to server is to use FormData object. 
Client side my code is:

```
var files = new FormData();
var count = 0;
$('#tableSlideId tr').each(function() {

    var inputForm = $(this).find("th:first").children();
    file = inputForm[0].files[0];
    files.append((count++).toString(),file);
});


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/sendFiles",
    data: files,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

}).done(function(err){

    var text ="";
    if(err) {

        text = "Upload FAILED! Retry ...";

    } else {

        text = "Upload SUCCES!";

    }

    alert(text);



});
```

Now server side i need to access to each file stored in the FormData object in order to store them in a server's folder. So i try with the following code:

```
 app.post('/sendFiles', function(req,res) {

    new formidable.IncomingForm().parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error', err)
          throw err
        }

       // console.log('Files', files);
       daoQuery.insertPdf(files);
      })
    res.end();

});
```

where `daoQuery.insertPdf()` function is defined as:

```
insertPdf: function(files){

    //var form = new FormData(files);
    //console.log(files);

  for(var key in files){

    //console.log("--->", files[key])

fs.writeFile(".\\dataset\\newFile.pdf", files[key].path, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 

 }

}
```

In this way I obtain a pdf file in the folder but it has 1KB size(that is not the original file's size) and if i try to open it the system says that the file is damaged.
I'm quite sure that the `FormData` object is recieved correctly from the server, infact in "insertPdf" function the print `console.log('Files', files)` gives me all the fields of the file ( like name, size, type = application/pdf, path and so on).

Answer (score 2):

I solved modifying the insertPdf function as follow:

```
insertPdf: function(files){

    //var form = new FormData(files);
    //console.log(files);

  for(var key in files){

    //console.log("--->", files[key])
    fs.readFile(files[key].path, function(err1,data){

    if(err1) throw err;

     fs.writeFile(".\\dataset\\newFile.pdf", data, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }); 


});
```